# Netty ChannelHandlerContext.write() not working

Tags: c#, netty

I'm writing a server with `Netty`. Unfortunately the `write()` or `writeAndFlush()` methods aren't working for me.

I have a Handler that extends `ChannelDuplexHandler`. It receives messages from a `C# client`, prints them and sends a message back. The client never receives the message so I don't know if they really get sent.

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)
{
    String input = msg.toString();
    System.out.println("Input = " + input); // This works fine
    ctx.writeAndFlush("Test");
    ctx.write("Test 1 2 3"); // This doesn't work.
}
```

This is my pipeline:

```
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception 
{
    ch.pipeline().addLast("idleStateHandler", ish);
    ch.pipeline().addLast("frameDecoder", new LineBasedFrameDecoder(maxIncMessageLength));
    ch.pipeline().addLast("stringDecoder", new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    ch.pipeline().addLast("stringEncoder", new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    ch.pipeline().addLast("myChannelDuplexHandler", gsh);
}
```

So my question is, why isn't `write()` working? Thanks.

**EDIT**: For testing purposes I just added

```
    final ChannelFuture f = ctx.writeAndFlush("Test"); 
    if(f.isDone())
        System.out.println("done!");
    if(f.isSuccess())
        System.out.println("real success!");
    f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
            System.out.println("complete!");
        }
    });
```

The output was:
done!
real success!
complete!

Could the problem be on the client end?

Comment: It actually seems to be a problem on the client side. I used a `StreamReader` until now which didn't work, but if I just read bytewise, I get input.

Comment: Seems like you forgot to append a newline character? '\n'